# custom uitableview with a tab bar on top ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbar

http://www.iospirations.com/component/iphoneinspirations/detail/198-burgerquest

#### screenshot

[image: ss of dialog]

I was wondering what I need to know to create a screen like this. I want to design the table with the tabs and also buttons across the bottom which seems to be a tab bar. I was looking around and I was thinking I might need to create a custom container class to re-position the tab bar to the position of the tabs on top of the table. But it also seems like there's a tab bar at the bottom. I'm not sure if that's even possible to create to tab bars in one view. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the step you need to follow in order to make the following view :-

1: Take a UITabBarController and set it as the rootViewController of your application window.

2: Now add Five Tab to this UITabbarController .

3: Add five seperate UINavigationController to each Tab individually.

4: Now add five different UIViewControllers to the UINavigationController respectively.

5: Create a Custom Tabbar now :

5.1 : One of the way of creating custom Tabbar is to take a UIView of Tabbar height and add 
         UIButtons as Tab to the Tabbar.

6: Add the Custom tabBar on to the MainWindow . On choosing various button on your custom 
   tabbar change the setSelectedIndex of your application UITabbarController.

7: Now how to create the view you showed in screenshot ,

7.1: Take two buttons on the Top of a UITableView (in your case for "Last" & "Top 10") .
        Now whenever the user clicks on any button change the background image (image 
        indicating selected state) for that button and also simulataneuosly changes the image 
        for other button (image   indicating unselected state ).

7.2: Also reload the tableView everytime time any of the buttons clicked with the different 
        data for both the button

8: You can create custom UITableViewCell in order to create Rows in the TableView.
    Here is link explaining how to create custom UITableViewCell:-
    http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

Comment: Thanks for the guide lines. Im gonna follow what you listed and hopefully I will be able to make what I need too. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user2337981 You are most welcome . I would appreciate more if you vote up me for my efforts

Comment: Looks mostly like a hack. Is there any straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

If I was doing this from scratch, I'd use a `UITabBar` at the bottom and a `UISegmentedControl` at the top. These can both be customised to whatever style you're looking for (as long as you're using iOS5+).

Comment: UISegmentedControl seems logical from context point-of-view. Also, it's easily portable when you deploy cross-platforms.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to a small part of your question, multiple tab bars is a definite no no. A standard UITabBarViewController is intended only to be the root view controller for a window. It might work, but it will eventually break in an iOS update. Been there.